# Large blobs of colors while changing UIImage curves?

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

I am trying to create some cool effects for a picture app of mine. I'm using [this project](https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters) to aid my process in changing curves, brightens, contrast, etc.

Here's the code I am using:

```
- (UIImage*)coolifyTheImage {
UIImage *image = self;
NSArray *redPoints = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 43)],
                      [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(52, 136)],
                      [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(107, 201)],
                      [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(255, 255)],
                      nil];
NSArray *greenPoints = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 27)],
                        [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(54, 86)],
                        [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(214, 219)],
                        [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(214, 255)],
                        nil];
NSArray *bluePoints = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, 86)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(49, 86)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(122, 100)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(201, 167)],
                       [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(255, 167)],
                       nil];

image = [[[image applyCurve:redPoints toChannel:CurveChannelRed] 
          applyCurve:greenPoints toChannel:CurveChannelGreen]
         applyCurve:bluePoints toChannel:CurveChannelBlue];

return image;
}
```

It works beautifully on the bottom half of the image, but not the top. Here's what it's supposed to look like (screenshot taken from photoshop):

[image]

Here's the settings in photoshop:

[image]

[image]

And here's how it comes out after I ran the code on it:

[image]

In the picture, there is a massive section of blue and after changing the curves of the blue, that's what comes up. Is this a problem with the main function for adding curves or should I change the points?

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a guess, but are you sure that you're getting a straight line segment between the last 2 endpoints on the green and blue curves? Generally, if you apply a cubic curve in the same way as Photoshop, you'll get a large hump or dip in that section. Photoshop has a special handling of the endpoints, where everything after them is straight, but the math doesn't work out that way in general.

EDIT:
In fact, you can test this by passing a black to white gradient through it and seeing what the results are. Ideally a single scan-line would look like your graph, but if it doesn't, that's the problem.

Comment: I replaced it with a black/white gradient, and they look exact. Well, there is a small black line at the very top on the coded version (not photoshop)...

Comment: OK, then is there anything else going on with the image before or after you pass it through the curves? Does the order of passing it through the curves make any difference?

Comment: Nothing happens before. And no, the order doesn't matter.

Comment: I got it! If I changed the end points to 256 instead of 255, the blobs disappear! Not sure why, though...

Comment: Sounds like an off-by-one bug in the image library you're using.